# Como utilizar o like em uma comparação de campos em tabelas diferentes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como posso utilizar o *LIKE* para uma comparação de dois campos de tabelas diferentes? Preciso comparar os 5 primeiros caracteres de cada campo. Tentei com *SUBSTRING* e com *LEFT*, porém, o desempenho fica muito ruim.

Seguem duas maneiras que apliquei, com o comentário sinalizando:
1)

```
    SELECT(SELECT sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT)
                FROM SD3010 AS sd3_sub1         
                WHERE sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'                    
                    AND YEAR(D3_EMISSAO) = YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)  AND MONTH(D3_EMISSAO) = MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)
                    AND sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL BETWEEN '01' AND '02'
                    AND sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
                    /*AQUI UTILIZEI O LEFT*/   
                    AND LEFT(sd3_sub1.D3_CC, 5) = LEFT(sd3.D3_CC,5)
                    AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*') AS producao
    FROM SD3010 AS sd3
```

2)

```
    SELECT(SELECT sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT)
                    FROM SD3010 AS sd3_sub1         
                    WHERE sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'                    
                        AND YEAR(D3_EMISSAO) = YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)  AND MONTH(D3_EMISSAO) = MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)
                        AND sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL BETWEEN '01' AND '02'
                        AND sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
                        /*AQUI UTILIZEI O SUBSTRING*/   
                        AND SUBSTRING(sd3_sub1.D3_CC,1,5) = SUBSTRING(sd3.D3_CC,1,5)
                        AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*) AS producao
    FROM SD3010 AS sd3
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo do valor do campo `sd3.D3_EMISSAO`?

Comment: @Sorack seria uma data, por exemplo "20170222"

Comment: uma string representando uma data?

Comment: @Sorack Sim...me quebram as pernas =(

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro: se executa a consulta 1 sem comparar a coluna D3_CC, em quantos % a consulta fica mais rápida? // Observe que na cláusula WHERE da subconsulta há construções que a tornam non-sargable, o que faz com que ocorra varredura completa (index ou table scan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago, considerando-se que a coluna D3_EMISSAO está provavelmente declarada como *var*char(8), e com o valor armazenado no formato aaaammdd, me parece desnecessário, e talvez ineficiente, o uso das funções Year() e Month() para comparação entre a consulta externa e a interna, podendo a comparação ser efetuada diretamente no ambiente *string*.

Por exemplo, no lugar de

```
... YEAR(D3_EMISSAO) = YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)  
AND MONTH(D3_EMISSAO) = MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)
```

pode ser utilizado

```
Left(sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO, 6) = Left(sd3.D3_EMISSAO, 6)
```

Tanto o uso da funções Year/Month quanto da função Left, nesse caso específico, tornam a restrição *non [sargable](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)*. Há até como tornar essa construção *sargable*, ao implementar algo como

```
sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO between (Left(sd3.D3_EMISSAO, 6) + '01') 
                            and (Left(sd3.D3_EMISSAO, 6) + '31')
```

---

Não me parece que a causa da baixa performance seja o uso da função Left (ou Substring) na comparação da coluna D3_CC. A construção

```
LEFT(sd3_sub1.D3_CC, 5) = LEFT(sd3.D3_CC,5)
```

não me pareceu ineficiente, exceto, é claro, por ser uma construção *non [sargable](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)*. Mas há várias outras restrições presentes na cláusula WHERE que também a tornam *non sargable*.

Entretanto, há situações em que o LIKE pode ser mais eficiente do que o Left ou Substring. Mas isto depende de uma conjunção de fatores como índices disponíveis, a *lista_de_colunas*, a construção que contém o LIKE etc.
No caso de sua consulta, talvez a construção

```
       and sd3_sub1.D3_CC like Left(sd3.D3_CC,5) + '%'
```

possa ser mais eficiente.

---

Eis sugestão para o seu código, onde as construções *non sargable* foram substituídas por outras *sargable*:

```
-- código #1 v3
SELECT ...,
       (SELECT Sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT)
          from SD3010 as sd3_sub1         
          where sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'                    
               and sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL between '01' AND '02'
               and sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
               and sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO between (Left(sd3.D3_EMISSAO, 6) + '01') 
                                           and (Left(sd3.D3_EMISSAO, 6) + '31')
               and sd3_sub1.D3_CC like Left(sd3.D3_CC,5) + '%'
               and sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*') as producao
  from SD3010 AS sd3
  where sd3.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
        and ...;
```

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro: o código #1 v3 é sargable; resta saber se há índices que atendam ou se, mesmo assim, ocorrerá varredura sequencial.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso um `JOIN` é mais interessante do que uma `subquery`. Segue o exemplo para o caso `2`:

```
SELECT sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT) AS producao
  FROM SD3010 AS sd3 WITH(NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN SD3010 AS sd3_sub1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
  WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO) = DATEPART(YEAR, sd3.D3_EMISSAO)
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO) = DATEPART(MONTH, sd3.D3_EMISSAO)
    AND SUBSTRING(sd3_sub1.D3_CC,1,5) = SUBSTRING(sd3.D3_CC,1,5)
    AND sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'
    AND sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL BETWEEN '01' AND '02'
    AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
  GROUP BY sd3.D3_FILIAL
```

Haviam campos também sem `alias`.

Adicionei também o `WITH(NOLOCK)` também, que indica para o `SQL Server` que não é necessário bloquear a tabela enquanto a leitura dos dados é realizada.

Comment: Está como subquery porque existem outros select também. Tentei fazer um select só para cada, e usar o union, mas não permite porque a quantidade de registros é diferente...vou tentar usar desta maneira que você indicou e aviso na sequencia